# Python String Encoding - How to Remove "\012" in UTF-8 Strings

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing a website/search engine, and the results cannot have characters that are not UTF-8 or my pages get 500 server errors. The results come from a PostgreSQL database, and originally had some non UTF-8 characters. To fix my problem, I used the Python `.encode('utf-8')` function on my text and then reinserted it into the database. However, now my text has "\012" written through it. Is there anything I can do to the text when I retrieve it to format this away?

Comment: If the "/012" strings are meaningless and you just want them gone, you could just do `myString.replace("/012", "")`

Comment: That replace function didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The octal number 12 ('\012) is the decimal number 10, or the newline character:

```
>>> '\012'
'\n'
```

Strip or replace the newlines in your text before putting the text in the database.

But you don't *have*  to; it's a valid UTF-8 character.